# Which USB programmer can be used for a Winbond PLCC32 BIOS chip?

Tags: motherboard, memory

I have a Winbond BIOS chip W49F002UP12B and I want to program it using an USB programmer. I know the form is called PLCC32.

I found this [adapter](https://a.aliexpress.com/_EJ0FFJP). I think it's the right one.

But I do not know which programmer to use.

I found the [K150 programmer](https://a.aliexpress.com/_ExofYTT). There is a long list of supported chip types. But I don't know them and which type mine is.

Than there is the [SP200SE](https://a.aliexpress.com/_EQ3ZZl3) programmer. It explicitly says it's for Winbond. But it also says it's for SCM 24/93 chips. So I don't know if it works for my chip.

Can anyone tell me which programmer to use? Please tell me one from Aliexpress under 15€ (shipping included). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K150 you mentioned is wrong, since it's PIC only (PIC's are 8 bit micro-controllers from Microchip).

I believe SP200SE will not work either, since [I was able to find a document](https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/27/SP200S%20USER%20GUIDE.pdf) that mentions support only for Winbond W78.

What you are looking is [something like this](https://www.ebay.de/itm/271313593347?hash=item3f2b8ce403:g:0jYAAOSw3KFWcTcz&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAwD%2BWWli52XrREvFGX3AGq3%2FsDFvVZvrTUpfRjJkjCzG0eZ%2FLZe5kqofyKrx52rb3dLEWL43Qrsrz683y8d6s3rbh1%2FgmyJoMeZrwD3rvhuDmXJoPXp88p6S%2BtS9wlUE9dCOCli36TMlnj%2F44LXh%2F2seHuqfGMWPt60O07fo%2Bf%2FO35yKyGOdAaiVhuV9Alq6gWiO%2BN1iorzTDJo%2FUXWseOOKBYLavF1Hywjkg3XNNJMQROlGFScO7EmCkHZirV6R%2BEA%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5DqnKSTYQ):

[image]

Description specifically mentions it is able to program Winbond W49F002, which is your case.

Anyway, looks like W49 is rather old stuff dated around 2000, so finding this kind of outdated programmer might be tricky. Good luck with your search!

Comment: If I use this programmer then I also need the legacy adapter. All together it's 48€ what is quite extensive. Isn't there something cheap on Aliexpress for below 20€?

Comment: I have no idea. I'm afraid you have to find this by yourself. Another option would be to find someone who would be able to help you out with this - someone at eevblog should definitely have this kind of programmer.

Comment: No problem I think I can't get it this cheap. But I found another programmer called TL866II Plus for those who are interested. It supports 18.000 devices and costs around 60€ with all adapters. List of supported devices is here https://www.hklrf.com/24download/img/TL866II_List5.txt